# G suite mail automatic mail copying to admin

Tags: php, email, smtp, gmail, google-workspace

I have 3 admins in my G-suite. One is - Admin1.

Now, what i want, whenever a specific user - User1, send email, anywhere. It automatically gets copied - to Admin1.

How to do this ? Thanks in advance for kindness n help.

Answer (score 0):

It can be - DONE, using ROUTING feature of G-Suite.

[image]